# Is it possible to display select/dropdown option onload using jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Presently jqGrid provides with [inline-editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) where in the user has to click on a particular row in-order to know the jqgrid row has select/drop down option present;

Is it possible some how to display the dropdown/select to user on the grid load?

Similar to formatter options like 'link' or 'checkbox' which can be seen on the grid load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `loadcomplete` option in the Jqgrid

```
    $("#jQGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '../Controller/Action',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: [...],
        colModel: [...],
         .
         .
         .
        gridview: true,
        loadonce: true,
        loadComplete: function () { 

            //just make all the row to editmode

            ids = $("#jQGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            var l = ids.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                $("#jQGrid").jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
            }
        },
        rowNum: 10
    });
```

Check [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) documentation for further events. Hope this helps.